# How to acces 'marshmallow.fields.String' class

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow

In my class ContactDetailsSchema I want to change phone number to exclude characters "-" and " " so I created function number_squish

```
def number_squish(number):
    remove_characters = ["-", " "]
    for character in remove_characters:
        number = number.replace(character, "")
    return number
```

```
class ContactDetailsSchema(Schema):

    contactName = fields.Method(serialize='name_name_2')
    telephone = fields.Str(attribute='phone')
```

When I try to access apply the function like `number_squish(fields.Str(attribute='phone'))`

```
AttributeError: 'String' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

How can I access marshmallow String class to change it?

```
<class 'marshmallow.fields.String'>

<fields.String(default=<marshmallow.missing>, attribute='phone', validate=None, required=False, load_only=False, dump_only=False, missing=<marshmallow.missing>, allow_none=False, error_messages={'required': 'Missing data for required field.', 'type': 'Invalid input type.', 'null': 'Field may not be null.', 'validator_failed': 'Invalid value.', 'invalid': 'Not a valid string.', 'invalid_utf8': 'Not a valid utf-8 string.'})>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question

The field that should have been modified by my function is phone not the whole field so telephone field should look like

```
telephone = fields.Str(attribute='number_squish')
```